# Can you point me to a cable that will connect this motherboard port with this DVD drive?

Tags: motherboard, sata, dvd, cable, ata

(Note: This is **not** a duplicate of my earlier question, in case you're wondering. This question has an entirely different DVD drive!)

Here is an image of my laptop motherboard's SATA connector (for a DVD drive):

[image]

I don't see any model number on the motherboard. The laptop is Acer Extensa model MS2394, purchased a few months ago (came with Windows 8 or 8.1 installed).

This is a matching SATA port for an internal DVD drive:

[image]

Problem is, the DVD drive doesn't fit into the laptop.

**QUESTION:** Can you point me to a cable that will connect the two together? This way, the "internal" DVD drive could be used as an external DVD drive. It's an ugly setup with a permanent SATA cable coming out of an opening of the laptop, but I don't care about that.

I've been searching for "SATA cable" but there are so many alternatives. I don't know which to pick. Isn't there a simple (and long enough) SATA to SATA "extension" cable, so to speak?

Answer (score -1):

I didn't noticed there's a different space between connections. The first one is Slimline SATA, while the second is mini SATA (mSATA). What I would've suggest you is to buy mSATA to USB cable (you can find in on aliexpress), as it is way easier to buy, when Slimline to mSATA may be impossible to at all.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I think now it does.

Comment: @user5292408 Very interesting! Would it also work to buy a slimline SATA DVD drive? (I don't actually own the DVD drive mentioned in the question, so I still could buy a Slimline SATA DVD drive if that would help.) In this case, is there a cable available to connect the Slimline motherboard connector with the slimline SATA DVD drive (since the DVD drive still won't fit into the laptop)?

Comment: @user5292408 Actually, how did you see that the motherboard is slimline SATA but the DVD drive in the question is mSATA? I don't see it obviously. To my untrained eye it would seem to fit but I must be wrong.

Comment: Holy s. I went full retarded here. What you're looking for is male-female Slimline SATA cable (both are Slimline, mSATA is "straight"). Amazon [link](http://www.amazon.com/Cables-Unlimted-FLT601018-Slim-line-Motherboard/dp/B0022NI0L4/ref=sr_1_3?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1441483831&sr=1-3&keywords=slimline+sata+cable). mSATA is used for example in SSD drives.

@HardwareIgnoramus they're both Slimlines, don't know why I thought it they were different, so you can use normal Slimline male-female cable or, what I've suggested, usb-slimline cable, as it's more comfortable to detach.